# having a subdirectory in a different host between IIS 10 and Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, iis, url-rewriting, arr

We have a IIS based website : www.example.com. with IP address of A.A.A.A. now the content team wants to have a wordpress blog to be addressed www.example.com/blog. and it is on a CentOS Linux machine with the IP address of B.B.B.B 
How should I do this?? I know that I have to use ARR but so far my attempts haven't been successful. 
and what would be the host name of the Linux machine?? should I install wordpress in a sub directory in there too??

Comment: This is a broad question...  **1** do you mind if the user sees that he is redirected?  i.e. the address bar value changes?  Yes: setup a proxy.  No: setup a redirection.  **2** you will have to it setup on A.A.A.A (so IIS), pointing to B.B.B.B.  **3** the hostname of the Linux machine can be anything, define it in the DNS.  **4** since WordPress is already installed, no point installing it again on A.A.A.A.

Comment: thanks. I prefer that url remain in the same format. can you help me in configuration?? reverse proxy in IIS doesn't work the way it should. it either redirects all traffic or nothing. I have problem in setting the pattern.

Comment: So you want the proxy option.  I am not an IIS guy.  In Apache I would use `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`, but I have no idea how to do it in IIS. My configuration would proxy `/blog` to `http://DOMAIN_FOR_B/wordpress` or whatever the URL is for the WordPress.  Do not proxy `/`, that will apply on everything.

Comment: actually I found examples of what you said and method for Apache, but there is nothing between IIS and Apache and url-rewriting. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should find IIS proxy configuration examples.  Source would be "/blog", target would be the URL that points to the WordPress site.

Comment: Reveal what is exactly "my attempts" as part of the question even if they "haven't been successful", as they can help others understand your entire setup. Also you should describe the overall networking setup, like which is the first server to take external traffic, IIS/Windows or CentOS. ARR is only useful if IIS/Windows is the first server and then it can dispatch requests to CentOS.

Comment: of cource IIS/Windows is the first server. i have setted the pattern to "exact match" and the value is "example.com/blog". I have enabled the reverse proxy to the IP of the CentOS. and for now I don't even want to see wordpress. I just want to see Apache default page. the problem is I don't know which parameters I should config in IIS. should I approach from server farm? or should just give the IP address of CentOS? anyway, neither has been successful